# Crystal report when exported to pdf looks different on development machine and server

Tags: pdf, crystal-reports

I am exporting crystal report to pdf format. On development machine the pdf document looks perfect but on server, the right hand section of entire pdf document is cut off a little bit.

I am using sub reports. On server the right border of all the sub reports and minor text is getting cut off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggests here that in the Crystal Report client, go to Page Setup and select No Printer.

[Crystal Report create strange PDF format on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910927/crystal-report-create-strange-pdf-format-on-server)

That might resolve your difference in the output.

Comment: I did make the above change. But now, even the pdf on my localhost changes as seen on server. This setting does not work for me.

Comment: Not a solution but you could try moving the report items to the left and see if it doesn't get chopped. I've noticed quirks like this with crystal report exports too.

Comment: Yes, I had to set "No printer" option as well as reformat my crystal reports.

Comment: Thanks alot! I'm currently porting a client application to a web application and had the exact same problem. I'd have NEVER guessed that solution.